# Right tapped event not firing on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have an image with tapped and right tapped event . But when I run it right tapped event not firing instead tapped event is again executing . Here is my code

```
  private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog p = new MessageDialog("tapped");
        p.ShowAsync();

    }

    private void Image_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog p = new MessageDialog(" right tapped");
        p.ShowAsync();
    }
```

I dont know why this is happening.

Comment: What are you doing to try to trigger the `RightTapped` event?

Comment: Yes but tapped event is calling instead of right tapped.

Comment: I have two different things to perform on image tap and the other on right tap

Comment: I tried both my mouse buttons but same methos is calling.

Comment: I check again n again please need help?

Comment: On your phone, how are you trying to trigger the `RightTapped` event?